# Compile typescript namespaces with less code duplication

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces, typescript2.0

I'm using gulp-typescript to transpile my typescript files into JS. And it all works fine, except I'm surprised that namespaces are duplicated for every file in the resulting .js file.
Take this example:

`LettersOnlyValidator.ts`:

```
namespace Validation {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

`ZipCodeValidator.ts`:

```
namespace Validation {
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles into `app.js`:

```
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    class LettersOnlyValidator {
        isAcceptable(s) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
    Validation.LettersOnlyValidator = LettersOnlyValidator;
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    class ZipCodeValidator {
        isAcceptable(s) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
    Validation.ZipCodeValidator = ZipCodeValidator;
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
```

This is my expected outcome:

```
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    class LettersOnlyValidator {
        isAcceptable(s) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    class ZipCodeValidator {
        isAcceptable(s) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
    Validation.LettersOnlyValidator = LettersOnlyValidator;
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
```

Is there any compile options to optimize that? I couldn't find anything in the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Or is there a technical reason. e.g. scope conflict for it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no. But I haven't done much Typescript since...